# How to get the orthographic scaling of the camera to be exact in conjunction with the grid in isometric view?

Tags: camera, image

Is there an exact orthographic scaling that accurately reaches the top of the grid angle?
I use "1.4142" in ortographic scale. But I'm not sure it's accurate enough.

I use a resolution of 1024x1024.

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: There is always an approximation, but with that parameters you should get something pretty close. Can you show the discrepancy? In my test file seems aligned enough...https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8b60.png

Comment: The discrepancy is not noticeable in resolutions of 2048x2048 (literal, the same pixels in terms of similar orthographic scaling), which is enough, I still wanted to share the data, and also ask if anyone had the exact calculation haha, thanks for commenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this is to use the 1x1 plane centered at the origin as a guide (as you've already done visually here), and to programmatically fit the parameters of the orthographic camera to just-barely contain that plane. Assuming no shape keys or other complications to the vertex data are present, and that you have the reference 1x1 plane chosen as the `Active Object` currently, and that the only camera in the scene is called "Camera" and is the orthographic camera of interest, here's some Python code for doing this, using the location of the 1x1 plane's vertices in Camera Space as a way of determining how close the Orthographic Camera is to containing them:

```
from bpy_extras.object_utils import world_to_camera_view
vxMax = max([world_to_camera_view(bpy.context.scene, bpy.data.objects['Camera'], bpy.context.object.matrix_world @ v.co).x for v in bpy.context.object.data.vertices])
vxMin = min([world_to_camera_view(bpy.context.scene, bpy.data.objects['Camera'], bpy.context.object.matrix_world @ v.co).x for v in bpy.context.object.data.vertices])
vyMax = max([world_to_camera_view(bpy.context.scene, bpy.data.objects['Camera'], bpy.context.object.matrix_world @ v.co).y for v in bpy.context.object.data.vertices]) 
vyMin = min([world_to_camera_view(bpy.context.scene, bpy.data.objects['Camera'], bpy.context.object.matrix_world @ v.co).y for v in bpy.context.object.data.vertices])

xDiam = vxMax - vxMin
yDiam = vyMax - vyMin
diam = max(xDiam, yDiam)

bpy.data.objects['Camera'].data.ortho_scale = bpy.data.objects['Camera'].data.ortho_scale * diam
```

Notes:

- this simple code works nicely with a scene containing just the default camera (but switched to Orthographic) and with the Default Cube replaced by a Plane. It needs to be generalized a bit if the camera may be 'off-center' initially, in order to re-center the camera as well as adjust the orthographic scale
- this only 'exactly' fits to whichever of the two dimensions is most constraining, given the target object and the orthographic camera's resolution (changing the ratio of the x, y resolutions of the orthographic camera changes the shape of its "view box", which can change which dimension is the most constraining one). I think it's also not very hard to generalize this a bit further to *set* the ratio of x, y resolutions so that the resulting orthographic camera is an exact fit to the target object in both dimensions, though, if that's needed.
- this isn't really "exact", in the sense that I haven't explicitly worked out the mathematics of the basis transformations needed to compute the orthographic camera parameter settings needed to exactly fit to Blender's overlay grid. But, I think this is very close to that; the 1x1 plane centered at the World Origin seems to fit the overlay grid exactly, and working out the specifics of the basis transformations would I suspect ultimately end up with an implementation that looks basically like this code, since that is exactly the kind of mathematical transformation built-ins like `world_to_camera_view` are responsible for providing

Comment: Incredible, you solved it! and the camera was already centered if you add a camera with this:
`bpy.ops.object.camera_add(location=(30.60861, -30.60861, 30.60861))`
`object = bpy.context.scene.objects.active`
`object.rotation_euler = (0.955324, 0, 0.785398)`
`object.data.type = 'ORTHO'`
`object.data.ortho_scale = 14.123`
`object.name = "Camera"`
`bpy.ops.view3d.object_as_camera()`

For those who use Blender 2.79b and the code does not work(The @NeverConvex code) , they have to change the "@" to "*".
Thanks!